# Section indent or leftmargin

Tags: sectioning, indentation, titlesec

I use the **titlesec** package for decoration sections and subsections. But i do not know how to change *leftmargin* or *indent* for this. 
Look at the picture, the green line is where i want to move the section.

I use this code

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 14pt]{extreport}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}{}{\thesection}{14pt}{}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It would be very useful to add the code you have up to now. Is it the *blue* line?

Comment: @egreg i added code

Comment: That code produces an error.

Comment: but in texmaker this works without errors.

Comment: I don't think so. Please, make a complete example: only the class, the loading of `titlesec` and the relevant commands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A layout as you'd like can be obtained by

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength{\normalparindent}
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\normalparindent}{\parindent}}

\titleformat{name=\section}[block]
  {\LARGE}
  {\hspace*{\normalparindent}\thesection}
  {1em}
  {}

\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}[block]
  {\LARGE}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\hspace*{\normalparindent}}

\begin{document}

\section{Lorem Ipsum Dolor}
\lipsum[1]

\section*{Nam Dui Ligula}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

It's necessary to specify the `numberless` variant, otherwise the indentation would not be respected for unnumbered sections. Adjust the size (I used `\LARGE`) and the spacing between the number and the title (I used 1em).

The definition and setting of `\normalparindent` is necessary because the value of `\parindent` is *not* available (better, it's set to zero) when LaTeX is typesetting a section title.

---

[image]

---

**Note.** I don't like such a layout at all.